# Motorola XT460 CPS cable pinout

Tags: motorola

I want to connect a Motorola XT460 to PC. I also have the CPS software for it. Unfortunately, I do not have the cable; it seems impossible to order it.

Accordingly to my research it based on a UART TTL controller.

There is an option in CPS for the COM port and the station has 2 I/O contacts. Direct connection to TX and RX (in any combination) doesn't allow communications with the transceiver.

Maybe someone has more information about CPS cable pin-out or even ideas how to program such devices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the cable you need is Motorola part number RKN4155; there are a number of compatible products on sale which you can find with your preferred search engine. They are around $20-25 on eBay. It seems that this cable works by connecting the charger cup for the portable radio.

Comment: Unfortunately, its's impossible to order the cable in my region due to the war. So if you have a cable - can you please assist at least with research of it? I would appreciate any information - photo of PCB, wiring etc.

Comment: Also it is possible to use RKN4154a

Answer (score 0):

Great news - I found the solution, this cable it is a typical Motorola's 1-wire interface, but with Micro Type B USB connector.

Wiring is pretty simple:

- pins 2-3 should be short and used as a 1-wire data;
- pin - 5 is the ground wire (as is in USB).

Comment: Do you happen to have a visual diagram?